# How can I correct an "access denied - ./positive_images File not found - -iname" error?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I am trying to train my own classifier in order to use in my Java application - using JavaCV. So, I collect positive, cropped images and put them in the ./positive_images directory of the cloned repository following the tutorial http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html. Then I try to run the following command

```
find ./positive_images -iname "*.jpg" > positives.txt
```

and that returns
access denied - ./positive_images
File not found - -iname

The folder has full permissions.

Do anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: This is almost certainly a routine file/folder/path mistyping.  Did you run the command from the root of the repository, as the article suggests?

Comment: yes I have a folder with name open and there, there is the sub folder positives_images. When I run the command, my path is C:\open

Comment: ok the problem was the quotes.When I used ' instead of " the access denied problem was solved. But now when run the command it returns File not found - '*.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

You should try this: `find ./positive_images/* "*.jpg" > positives.txt` The quotations were good as-is. The -INAME isn't a viable paramater, so you should remove it. Also, find only works for files and not directories, so addin /* to the directory fixes the first problem.